# In angular2, empty value of a dropdown option is coming as the option name itself and not empty string

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<select (change)="setOrg($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
              <option value="" selected>Org</option>
              <option *ngFor="let org of orgs" value="{{org}}">{{org}}</option>
</select>
```

and the function is like this :-

```
setOrg(val) {console.log(val); }
```

When I select the 'Org' option, it should print an empty string (""), but it is printing 'Org' itself.
What's the issue here ?

Comment: The code you provided should work just fine. You'd need to provide some more code or try and reproduce the issue in a plunker.

Comment: It also doesn't sound like Angular related. I guess this is normal browser behavior when `value` is empty. Have you considered using `"-"` or similar as value? Also using `ngModel` and `[value]="''"` or `[ngValue]="''"` might help solving your issue.

Comment: I just figured out it's a typescript issue. while compiling to javascript from typescript, it removes the `value=""` code